# Contact Form 7: hook mail body

Tags: wordpress

I use wordpress Contact Form 7 plugin.

I have checkboxes that contains the product ID. When I send the email I need to hook the email body, so I could add the all data of the Product into the mail body.

Is there any way to hook the body?

Comment: Try at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

The plugin I usually use for that is [Contact Form 7 Dynamic Text Extension](http://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-dynamic-text-extension/) although it looks as though it hasn't been updated in over 2 years (slight concern). This one [HERE](http://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-modules/) says it supports custom fields if the Product ID is stored in one of those?